# Choose between “new Buffer(str)” and “Buffer.from(str)”

Tags: node.js, buffer, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

According to [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding), using `new Buffer(str)` is deprecated, and people should use `Buffer.from(str)` instead. On the other hand, `Buffer.from` wasn't available in older versions of node. According to [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) it was added in node 5.10.0.

So I had assumed that I could simply use code like

```js
buf = Buffer.from ? Buffer.from(str) : new Buffer(str);
```

to avoid deprecation warnings while maintaining compatibility with older versions of node. It turns out this doesn't work as expected. Some older versions of node do seem to have a `from` method, but an incompatible one that throws an exception:

```
TypeError: this is not a typed array.
    at Function.from (native)
```

So how would I go about picking the right version? Should I test `process.version` somehow? Or is there some cleaner solution which might be better suited to the possibility of other engines compatible with but not identical to node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newer Buffer API was [backported to v4.x in v4.5.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V4.md#4.5.0). The `Buffer.from()` you see in versions prior to that is `Uint8Array.from()`, which is not the same thing.

A better API test might be checking the existence of `Buffer.allocUnsafe()`.